# MVC 5 UrlHelper without HTTPContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontext, hangfire

I decorate my MVC 5 actions with route attributes:

```
[Route("this-test")] 
public ActionResult ThisTest()
```

and with a HTTPContext I can access the route name like so:

```
UrlHelper helper = new UrlHelper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
string actionUrl = helper.Action("ThisTest", "Home");
```

However I'm using Hangfire chron jobs to fire off some emails.  Since I don't have a HTTPContext I cannot use the code above to obtain my route of "home/this-test/".

Is this possible to achieve?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this topic:
[Passing site URL to hangfire recurrent jobs](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/passing-site-url-to-hangfire-recurrent-jobs/2641).

Relying on the answer there, there's no way to receive the domain inside a Hangfire job. It seems like passing the URL of your site as a parameter to a job is the most clear solution.